# SQL & Grafana & Microsoft Teams Incoming Webhook Hook

Tags: mysql, sql, grafana, microsoft-teams

It's possible to create this implementation:

Grafana check a SQL table, when a new raw appears, Grafana show that line in table dashboard and access incoming webhook url to Microsoft Teams

Have anyone some suggestion ?

Thanks!

Comment: You could test this by [setting up a custom incoming webhook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/connectors/connectors-using#setting-up-a-custom-incoming-webhook). Please let us know if you face any issues.

Comment: Hi, Thx but I know to use a icoming webhook, but my questions is: how Grafana can access this webhook ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you already found the solution or not but for anyone looking for the solution,  here is how this can be done:

1. Get the URL of the configured incoming webhook of the channel in MS Teams; Add and configure the Incoming webhook from connector screen first.
2. To setup the webhoot notification in Grafana, see https://grafana.com/docs/alerting/notifications/#webhook